# javascript pop up window all over the place

Tags: javascript

I am creating a popup form.  I am using the code below and I want the form to show up in the center of the page with the pre determined height/width.  The popup is all over the place.  It will pop up on the left top, right middle and with different sizes.  How can I set it to be consistent?

```
<a class="collapse-item" href="#" onclick="reqcred()">Cards</a>

    <script>
        function reqcred() {
            w = window.open("{% url 'test_popup' %}","popup_form", 'left=100,top=100,height=450,width=650');
            w.onload =
                function() {
            w.onunload = function() {
            location.reload(true);
        }}}
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you use a simple modal or does it have to be its own window?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  This is what I did.

```
<script>
    function reqcred() {
        var height = 750
        var width = 950
        var left = Number((screen.width/2)-(width/2));
        var top = Number((screen.height/2)-(height/2));

        w = window.open("{% url 'test_popup' %}","popup_form", 'width='+ width + ', height=' + height + ', top='
            + top + ', left=' + left);
        w.onload =
            function() {
        w.onunload = function() {
        location.reload(true);
    }}}
</script>
```